# Set volume to docker container from wsl from windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In my windows i installed docker and ubuntu 18.4 wsl.So after expose daemon on localhost, i can use windows daemon on ubuntu wsl.

I created a directory's on drive d and i made a file into data directory like below:

```
PS D:\wsl\data> dir
    Directory: D:\wsl\data
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        8/31/2019   2:27 PM              0 New Text Document.txt
PS D:\wsl\data>
```

after that, i run a postgres container like below on wsl teminal:

```
$ docker run  --name=pg-docker3  -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=s123  -v /mnt/d/wsl/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data mdillon/postgis:11-alpine
```

After creating container i open container by bash :

```
$ docker exec -it pg-docker3 bash
```

This is data postgres directory:

```
bash-4.4# ls /var/lib/postgresql/data
PG_VERSION            pg_commit_ts          pg_logical            pg_serial             pg_subtrans           pg_xact               postmaster.pid
base                  pg_dynshmem           pg_multixact          pg_snapshots          pg_tblspc             postgresql.auto.conf
data                  pg_hba.conf           pg_notify             pg_stat               pg_twophase           postgresql.conf
global                pg_ident.conf         pg_replslot           pg_stat_tmp           pg_wal                postmaster.opts
bash-4.4#
```

as you can see `data` directory construct in location but when i listed thing's inside data directory i can see my text file that created in host machine !!!

I created a directory inside data directory calld `kk`.

```
bash-4.4# ls /var/lib/postgresql/data
PG_VERSION            pg_commit_ts          pg_logical            pg_serial             pg_subtrans           pg_xact               postmaster.pid
base                  pg_dynshmem           pg_multixact          pg_snapshots          pg_tblspc             postgresql.auto.conf
data                  pg_hba.conf           pg_notify             pg_stat               pg_twophase           postgresql.conf
global                pg_ident.conf         pg_replslot           pg_stat_tmp           pg_wal                postmaster.opts
bash-4.4# ls /var/lib/postgresql/data/data/
kk
bash-4.4#
```

But not create this directory inside host as you can see:

```
PS D:\wsl\data> dir

    Directory: D:\wsl\data

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        8/31/2019   2:27 PM              0 New Text Document.txt
```

Where is the `/var/lib/postgresql/data/data/` ? and why it not appeared in /mnt/d/wsl/data ?

Answer (score 0):

You must move your mounting path from /mnt to /. In this answer there is the following explanation : [Can you run Docker natively on the new Windows 10 (Ubuntu) bash userspace?](https://serverfault.com/a/790806/355581)

**Volumes**

Take care when adding volumes. The path `C:\dir` will be visible as `/mnt/c/dir` on WSL and as `/c/dir/` by docker engine. You can overcome it permanently:

```
sudo bash -c "echo -e '[automount] \nroot = /'>/etc/wsl.conf"
```

You must exit and reload WSL after making the change to wsl.conf so that WSL reads in your changes on launch.

Regards

Comment: I do your suggestion and after running code i run `Restart-Service LxssManager` from powershell. now all windows drive are in root `wsl@wsl: /
$ ls @carlosRafaelRamirez
bin   c  dev  f  home  lib    media  opt   root  sbin  srv  tmp  var
boot  d  etc  g  init  lib64  mnt    proc  run   snap  sys  usr     
wsl@wsl: /` @CarlosRafaelRamirez

Comment: I create postgresql container,  i got error https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nhjm3KWNGf/ @CarlosRafaelRamirez

Comment: You are near, probably it now is getting the right directory from Windows. I don't know how to solve the permissions problem. If changing the permissions in windows will make the difference or if it is a way that postgress ignore the permissions

Comment: Maybe you are right i will try to ignore permissions. Thanks @CarlosRafaelRamirez